# Use npm datetimepicker library in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-mix

I am trying to use a library installed through npm: https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker

I add it to the file in resources app.js next to jquery:

```
require('bootstrap');
window.$ = require('jquery');
window.jQuery = require('jquery');
window.datetimepicker = require("jquery-datetimepicker");
```

I have also tried to add it like this:

```
window.$.datetimepicker = require("jquery-datetimepicker");
```

And in page I use this code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.date').datetimepicker({step:30});
})
```

But always get the same error:
$(...).datetimepicker is not a function

If I add the libraries directly, it works.

```
<link href="/js/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/js/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following...

```
window._ = require('lodash');
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require("jquery-datetimepicker");
require('bootstrap');

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.date').datetimepicker({step:30});
})
```

And make sure to add `{{ mix('css/app.css') }}` at the top and `{{ mix('js/app.js') }}` at the bottom.